# How to scroll to the specified line in QPlainTextEdit?

Tags: qt

Assuming I have a line number in the variable ln.

```
int ln=25;
```

When I pass ln to QPlainTextEdit, the scrollbar will scroll to the line 25 in QPlainTextEdit.

How to implement this feature? Could anybody give me some advice? I would be very grateful

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use [`QPlaintextEdit::document`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qplaintextedit.html#document) to get the `QTextDocument`.

Use [`QTextDocument::findBlockByLineNumber`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtextdocument.html#findBlockByLineNumber) to get `QTextBlock` of a specific line number. Remember though, it starts from line 0, not line 1.

Then create a `QTextCursor` using this `QTextBlock` and set it to your `QPlainTextEdit`.

```
int ln=25;
QTextCursor cursor(p_textEdit->document()->findBlockByLineNumber(ln-1)); // ln-1 because line number starts from 0
p_textEdit->setTextCursor(cursor);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. As your said, the cursor can move to the line 25, but I need to slide the scrollbar to find the cursor's position. How can I let the scrollbar scroll to the cursor's postion automatically? (e.g. the line 25 should be at the top in QPlainTextEdit)

Comment: @archangel Then you just have to scroll to the bottom first: `p_textEdit->moveCursor(QTextCursor::End);`

Comment: I'm very sorry to reply you so late. Putting p_textEdit->moveCursor(QTextCursor::End); before p_textEdit->setTextCursor(cursor); is really effective. Thank you. I appreciate your help.